# Python Django NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django

i want to have a button to click on a post detail view, and go to it's edit page.... but i get this error:

this is my template:

```
<div class="psot">
    {% if post.published_date %}
        <div class="date">
            {{ post.published_date}}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <a class="btn btn-default" href='{% url "post_edit" pk=post.pk %}'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ post.text|linebreaks}}</p>
</div>
```

and this is my view:

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})    

def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
       form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
       if form.is_valid():
           post = form.save(commit=False)
           post.author = request.user
           post.published_date = timezone.now()
           post.save()
           return redirect('blog.views.post_detail', pk= post.pk)
       else:
           form = PostForm(instance=post)
           return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

this is my url patterns:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[09]+)/edit/$', views.post_new, name='post_edit'),
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
```

this is the error from django:

```
Reverse for 'post_edit' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[09]+)/edit/$']
```

and here is where error is happened(and it show's me):

```
{% url "post_edit" pk=post.pk %}
```

note: i have done this exactly step by step from a tutorial created by djangogirls...

Comment: there is another typo in my url where i have to edit my first url's view.post_new to views.psot_edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed out a hyphen in this regex:

```
(?P<pk>[09]+)
```

That means the regex only accepts 0s and 9s.

It should be:

```
(?P<pk>[0-9]+)
```

Then it will accept the digits 0 to 9.

Comment: thanks man, it got me for 3 days.... i re-wrote my view and template 10 time's and never checked my url's.....